# Why this left outer join produces wrong results?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, outer-join

I am confused in the following SQL (perhaps trivial) on `OUTER JOIN`.
I have 2 small tables `emp` and `deptno` i.e. that have records for employees and their departments. Their relationship is obviously `1-N` (but this is irrelevant).
I am trying to use an outer join to find the department no that has no employees working there. So I thought the correct solution is an `OUTER JOIN`.
If I do the following:

```
select d.deptno as d_deptno, e.deptno as e_deptno  
from dept d left outer join  emp e  
on d.deptno = e.deptno;
```

I get:

```
d_deptno    e_deptno  
10,         10  
10,         10  
10,         10  
20,         20  
20,         20  
20,         20  
20,         20  
20,         20   
30,         30  
30,         30  
30,         30   
30,         30  
30,         30  
30,         30  
40,         null
```

Ok, so I thought what I need is just the last row so I only need to modify my query as follows:

```
select d.deptno as d_deptno, e.deptno as e_deptno  
from dept d left outer join  emp e  
on d.deptno = e.deptno and e.deptno is null;
```

I.e. I added `and e.deptno is null`. For some reason if I did `e_deptno is null` the query could not be parsed (why?)
But the results I got were the following!

```
d_deptno  e_deptno  
10,       null   
20,       null   
30,       null   
40,       null
```

Why am I getting these results? What am I misunderstanding with `OUTER JOIN`s?

Comment: you should put second condition in where clause `where e.deptno is null`

Comment: Also, you cannot use alias in where condition.

Comment: @chetan:So I can not do `join on and or etc`?

Comment: yes you can do join on.. and... or.. etc.if you have multiple join condition but you should put literal comparison in where clause

Comment: @chetan:I am not sure how the literal comparison is something different than should not be placed as part of the `join` condition

Comment: Read this (warning: long) answer: [Using IS NULL or IS NOT NULL on join conditions - Theory question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630887/using-is-null-or-is-not-null-on-join-conditions-theory-question/6631535#6631535), especially the bold part that says: ***"My point is that these NULLs are created (in the result set) during the LEFT OUTER JOIN."*** The Null you see in the results of the 1st query, in line: `40, null` **is produced by the outer join.** It's not in the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition `e.deptno is null` needs to be in the `where` clause:

```
select d.deptno as d_deptno, e.deptno as e_deptno  
from dept d left outer join  emp e  
on d.deptno = e.deptno 
where e.deptno is null
```

This is because the `on` clause uses the conditions specified as the criteria to join rows from one table to the other - so it would only link to `emp` records that had a null `deptno`, and simultaneously a `deptno` matching the `dept` record.

Since these criteria are mutually exclusive, the query will never successfully link to an `emp` record, so the outer join ensures that nulls are returned for the `emp` values.

The `where` clause is applied after the join conditions - so moving the `is null` condition into the `where` clause ensures that only `dept` records with no matching `emp` records are selected.

`e_deptno is null` is not valid in this query in either the `on` clause or the `where` clause because `e_deptno` is only defined in the select clause (*after* the `on`, `where` and any grouping have been applied) - it would probably be valid in a having clause (in MySQL), however.

Comment: So what does my version of `on...and` do? Also any idea why `e_deptno` is not accepted as part of the query?

Comment: +1. `so it would only link to emp records that had a null deptno, and simultaneously a deptno matching the dept record` You mean that records from `emp` having a matching `e.deptno` **and** emp records having `deptno` as `null` right?

Comment: @Jim: I mean that in order to match, *each* `emp` record's `deptno` value would *simultaneously* have to be null, *and* match the `dept` record's value.