# MySQL left join: null elements be filtered by where

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have 2 MySQL tables: `join_test_l` and `join_test_r`.

***join_test_l:***

```
+------+------+
| ca   | cb   |
+------+------+
| a    | s    |
| b    | s    |
| c    | d    |
| d    | NULL |
+------+------+
```

***join_test_r:***

```
+------+------+
| cc   | cb   |
+------+------+
| a    | NULL |
| b    | s    |
| c    | d    |
| d    | NULL |
+------+------+
```

and when I tried to query with left join and a `<>` filter on the left table:

```
select * from join_test_l as l left join join_test_r as r on l.cb=r.cb where l.ca<>'c';
+------+------+------+------+
| ca   | cb   | cc   | cb   |
+------+------+------+------+
| a    | s    | b    | s    |
| b    | s    | b    | s    |
| d    | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+
```

the rows where `l.ca` is `null` remained.
and when I tried to query with left join and a `<>` filter on the right table:

```
select * from join_test_l as l left join join_test_r as r on l.cb=r.cb where r.cc<>'c';
+------+------+------+------+
| ca   | cb   | cc   | cb   |
+------+------+------+------+
| a    | s    | b    | s    |
| b    | s    | b    | s    |
+------+------+------+------+
```

all the rows where `r.cc` is `null` is also removed.

can any explain this?
I mean why the null values in the result set is filtered by `<>` clause?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using IS NULL or IS NOT NULL on join conditions - Theory question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6630887/3404097)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2700354/3404097)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: A [mcve] includes DBMS, version, a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (including input) (with table initializations formatted as tables) & diffable (hence ordered) desired output. But absolute basics of debugging say: Show that your program does what you expect as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. Research (in the manual & the web) minimal additional code giving a problem that you can't solve. Repeat, minimizing working code. Then ask re the (small) difference between working & problem examples.

Comment: `NULL` has no value, it is "indeterminate" and as such it cannot be equal to anything, even to another `NULL` (because both are indeterminate & you cannot know if they are the same or not). So for NULLs, you can't determine equal, & hence you also cannot determine **not** equal. It's a common frustration in SQL. You have to use `IS` when considering nulls: `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @Used_By_Already "NULL has no value" is echoed fuzzy unhelpful SQL-culture received [pseudo-]wisdom. In math & cs anything can be a value & operators map them to other values. Null is a value treated specially by SQL operators, which have the same names as normal math (including relational) operators but are different. The value null is used in a certain SQL approach to recording that other values have not been supplied. It is straightforward to talk about null as a value, and a big muddle to not. (Observe the question-begging obfuscation-obfuscating scare quotes around "indeterminate".)

Comment: @philipxy I am offering a few brief words to assist a SQL question - hence SQL gibberish is directly relevant. I can offer no critique on your fine answer expect to say it seems like killing an ant with an elephant gun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Re `<>` & `null`**

`x<>y` is `true` when `x` is not equal (in the normal sense) to `y` `and x is not null and y is not null`. It is `false` when `x` is equal (in the normal sense) to `y` `and x is not null and y is not null`. Otherwise it is technically `unknown`, but that happens to be treated as if it were `null` by operators/syntax like `is`.

Most SQL operators are like that--they return their normal results when each argument `is not null`, and `unknown` (treated like `null`) otherwise. 
SQL operators are not the normal relational or mathematical operators with the same names; they treat (the values) `unknown` & `null` specially. (Saying that `null` is not a value is fuzzy unhelpful SQL culture rhetoric.)

Re "the "normal sense of equal", from [the MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual 
12.3.2 Comparison Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html):

> Comparison operations result in a value of `1` (`TRUE`), `0` (`FALSE`), or `NULL`.

> - `<=>`
>
>   `NULL`-safe equal. This operator performs an equality comparison like the `=` operator, but returns `1` rather than `NULL` if both operands are `NULL`, and `0` rather than NULL if one operand is `NULL`. The `<=>` operator is equivalent to the standard SQL `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` operator.

Note `on` & `where` return rows for which the condition evaluates to `true`. Constraints are satisfied when they don't evaluate to `false`.

**Re `left join` `on` & `where`**

Learn what LEFT/RIGHT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left/right table rows extended by NULLs. FULL JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left & right table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or ON that requires a possibly NULL-extended column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns an OUTER JOIN into an INNER JOIN". You have that.

Read your SQL DBMS documentation.

Comment: Good answer; you may also mention about null-safe operator `<=>` in MySQL. +1

Comment: Took your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the logic in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM join_test_l as l
LEFT JOIN join_test_r as r
    ON l.cb = r.cb AND r.cc <> 'c';
```

The issue here is that the `WHERE` is filtering off records from the result set.  On the other hand, by moving the logic to the join, we retain every record in the left table `join_test_l`.  Then, records which did not join to anything would have `null` for every column in `join_test_r`.

Comment: thank you Tim, This kind of filtering works for some cases, but I still wanna know why the `null` values in the result set be filtered by `<>` clause.